# Explaining different results from Ordinary Kriging and Universal Kriging?

Tags: algorithm, spatial-statistics, statistics, kriging

When using either methods to create a surface from the same set of observations, these surfaces differ from each other.

Visually it can be seen in the differences of the following contours (overlaid; the Red is Ordinary Kringin, Purple is Universal).

What are the main differences in those methods so that they would create different results?

[image]

The surfaces were produces using [ArcMap's 3D analyst](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q90000003z000000) - Default parameters for both tools. I realize that not many people have access to those tools, so I've put online the produced surfaces [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8fr2aipb32ewxn3/surfaces.zip?dl=0). If you want to recreate the contours, in your software use base heights of 9 and step of 2.

Comment: This seems very broad.  What literature have you reviewed prior to posting?  For example, both seem to be mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging.  Are you able to focus this down to a single question as per the [Tour]?  Even here we have a few posts that look worth reviewing and referencing as prior research: http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bkriging%5D+universal+ordinary

Comment: You are right; too broad. Hopefully I 've narrowed down a bit. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Are you using tools from ArcGIS for Desktop, or something else?  Not being able to see how your results came about is all that holds me back from re-opening after your edit.

Comment: It shouldn't matter since it's a Question on how these two work, but yes I am. Mostly this Question aims as a reference for people looking for more information on the said methods. And a chance for someone to answer it better than I would.

Comment: If you are writing this to become Community Wiki, then there is a checkbox for that, and also an [tag:algorithm] tag that can be used.

Comment: I don't think I have the option anymore after I posted the Question. Feel free to change it.

Comment: There's no voting available on CW status but I'm open to what others think on whether this particular question should be CW. I'll remove it for now and see how it progresses. The comment "Mostly this Question aims as a reference for people looking for more information on the said methods." is what made me think a collaborative effort was being proposed and the asker seemed to agree.